# How we can use after test in case of Karate Framework?

Tags: karate

I am currently doing the automation testing of micro service where I need to create the data before the start of the test, which can be done using callOnce in karate-config.js. But now challenge is how should I Clean up this data after my all features are over. There are option like afterFeature and afterScenario but that will not work as I have 20+ feature file each having one or more scenarios.